# BeautifulSoup extract text after tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

Need to scrap text appears before and after script tag,
HTML:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap signal-row">
        <div class="signal-title">EUR/USD signal</div>
        <div class="ms-auto signal-value signal-color xh-highlight">
            <span class="timeago fw-normal small" datetime="1656687480000" timeago-id="10">1 day ago</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap signal-row">
        <div class="signal-title">
            From 
        </div>
        <div class="ms-auto signal-value signal-color xh-highlight">
            <span class="fw-normal small">UTC<script>w(tzo());</script>+05:30</span>
            <script class="">w(hhmm(1656687480));</script>20:28
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap signal-row">
        <div class="signal-title">
            Till 
        </div>
        <div class="ms-auto signal-value signal-color xh-highlight">
            <span class="fw-normal small">UTC<script>w(tzo());</script>+05:30</span>
            <script class="">w(hhmm(1656698280));</script>23:28
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="signal-row signal-status signal-color">
        Filled 
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap signal-row">
        <div class="signal-title">
            Sold at 
        </div>
        <div class="ms-auto signal-value signal-color user-select-all">
            <script>f('OCKGMP');</script>1.0407
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap signal-row">
        <div class="signal-title">
            Bought at 
        </div>
        <div class="ms-auto signal-value signal-color user-select-all">
            <script>f('OCKGML');</script>1.0408
        </div>
```

need to extract UTC and +5:30  and other details available different mentioned in html span tag eg :`<span class="fw-normal small">UTC<script>w(tzo());</script>+05:30</span>`
Tried using next_sibling but it returns nothing, tried using etree and xpath but this is also not returning anything.

I tried using lxml etree:

```
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
t = dom.xpath("//div[@class='ms-auto signal-value signal-color']/span/script/following-sibling::text()")
for i in t:
     print(i.text)
```

Using next siblling:

```
l = soup.find('script').next_siblings
```

Expected Output :
UTC +05:30
20:28

Comment: Some of the code you tried and an example of expected result will improve your question  and will lead to more specififc answers.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion updated my code with the solution I tried

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `.text` or `get_text()` method on your element, the script tag will be ignored.

```
soup.select_one('.card-body span').parent.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

**Note** *Assuming HTML is generated dynamically, so prerequisites differ from facts in your question.*

###### Example

It will select all the `<span>` and iterate over `ResultSet` to print the texts.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="card-body">
    <div>
        <div class="ms-auto signal-value signal-color xh-highlight">
            <span class="fw-normal small">UTC<script>w(tzo());</script>+05:30</span>
            <script class="">w(hhmm(1656687480));</script>20:28
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap signal-row">
        <div class="signal-title">
            Till 
        </div>
        <div class="ms-auto signal-value signal-color xh-highlight">
            <span class="fw-normal small">UTC<script>w(tzo());</script>+05:30</span>
            <script class="">w(hhmm(1656698280));</script>23:28
        </div>
    </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('.card-body span'):
    print(e.parent.get_text(' ', strip=True))
```

###### Output

```
UTC +05:30 20:28
UTC +05:30 23:28
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your solution it prints only UTC. 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for e in soup.select('.card-body span'):
    print(e.get_text())

Comment: The answer is based on the input from your question and the example works correctly. I suspect the source text is not the one you get as a response but the one you got from the developer tools. so this would take a completely different direction and this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exactly this focus